# How load custom map by using google map api?

Tags: android, android-maps

I would like to know that how load custom map by using google map api. Is that possible? I want to develop a kind of map app for stand alone mobile device which doesn't connect the internet. Could u please give me some advices?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably already figured it out or gave up. But I thought I would post my solution in case someone else stumbles across this.

My solution was to go to the custom map and download the KML data for the map (set it to be a feed). You will get a file with a feed now you can add a KML layer with that feed, like so:

```js
function init() {

    const initialPosition = { lat: 55.085868, lng: 8.570730 };

    const map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: initialPosition,
        zoom: 12
    });

    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map, position: initialPosition });
    
    var georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'YOUR GOOGLE KML FEED URL GOES HERE',
        preserveViewport: true, // teels the api to use the initial poz and soom
        map: map
    });
    
    georssLayer.setMap(map);

}
```

google documentation can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer

hope it helps someone